# How to select the all outer side of a div using after and before property

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Please see my html code .

```css
.new-div{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid orange;
  text-align:center;
}

.new-div::before{
content: "&nbsp";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 90;
background-color: gray;
left: 0;

}
.new-div::after{
content: "&nbsp";
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 90;
background-color: gray;
left: 0;

}
```

```html
 <div class="new-div">
  content
 </div>
```

here i want to make all outer side of the new-div with gray color using after and before property. How can i get this. When iam using after and before property i can get the 2 side only .

Please see the below picture  . I want the output like this .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the same what you want.

```css
.new-div{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid orange;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.new-div::before{
content: "&nbsp";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
height:100%;
background-color: gray;
left: 0;

}
.new-div::after{
content: "&nbsp";
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 90;
background-color: gray;
left: 0;

}
```

```html
 <div class="new-div">
  content
 </div>
```